Requires clause and friend injection
I am trying to have some fun with friend injection and requires clause but I got some trouble :
template<int X>
struct MaximumValue{};

template<int X>
auto injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<X>);

template<int X>
struct MaximumValueInjector {
    template<int U> requires(U == X)
    friend auto injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<U>) {}
};


int main() {
    MaximumValueInjector<0> _;
    injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<0>{});
}


That code does not compile with this error :
prog.cc:16:5: error: function 'injectMaximumValue<0>' with deduced return type cannot be used before it is defined
   16 |     injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<0>{});
      |     ^
prog.cc:5:6: note: 'injectMaximumValue<0>' declared here
    5 | auto injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<X>);
      |      ^
1 error generated.

On both gcc and clang
However, if I remove the requires(U == X)it compiles fine.
Since for me 0 == 0, I don't understand the problem.
Does anyone can help me ?
(I know a workaround is to make injectMaximumValue friend of MaximumValue too :))
Is it because the requires clause induce a change in the prototype, and then it does not overload exactly the same function ?

"Is it because the requires clause induce a change in the prototype, and then it does not overload exactly the same function ?" Yes.

Using the non-template friend auto injectMaximumValue(MaximumValue<X>) {} might be an option.
